# I've multiple classes which differs only a bit. Is there a better approach?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

still learning my way thorugh unity and c# i got the following problem.
Ive multiple classes which differs only a bit. Iam faceing now the problem that ive some methods which only needs the ID value of the class and name for my buildingsystem but i cant pass the list over as the list passed is always from a different type of object. Is there a better approach for this

Here the 2 sample classes + the function i want to pass the list later on to get just the ID + Name value of the class.

Class Electricty:

```
public class Electricity
{
public int electricityID;
public string electricityName;
public float electricityPower;
public double electricityCost;
public Sprite electricitySprite;
public bool isPlaced;
public Vector3 electricityPosition;

public Electricity(int id, string name, float power, double cost, Sprite sprite, bool placed, Vector3 position)
{
    this.electricityID = id;
    this.electricityName = name;
    this.electricityPower = power;
    this.electricityCost = cost;
    this.electricitySprite = sprite;
    this.isPlaced = placed;
    this.electricityPosition = position;

    Debug.Log("New Electricity created");

}
```

Class Security:

```
public class Security
{
public int securityID;
public string securityName;
public double securityCost;
public Sprite securitySprite;

public Security(int id, string name, double cost, Sprite sprite)
{
    this.securityID = id;
    this.securityName = name;
    this.securityCost = cost;
    this.securitySprite = sprite;

    Debug.Log("New Security created");

}
```

}

Function ive where the class List later will be passed to

```
public void StartBuildingSystem(List<Electricty> electricityList, int count, string name)
{
    uiPhone.SetActive(false);
    uiPlacement.SetActive(true);
    PlacingAreas(GetActiveBluePrint(name), GetActiveType(electricityList, name));
    activeBuildingType = GetActiveBuildingType(name);



    //uiPlacement.SetActive(false);
}


    public void StartBuildingSystem(List<Security> securityList, int count, string name)
{
    uiPhone.SetActive(false);
    uiPlacement.SetActive(true);
    PlacingAreas(GetActiveBluePrint(name), GetActiveType(securityListList, name));
    activeBuildingType = GetActiveBuildingType(name);



    //uiPlacement.SetActive(false);
}
```

Could anyone give me any idea what would be a better approach so i dont have to make multiple functions which does except same just get a different list passed over.

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to look up `Inheritance` https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_inheritance.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing would probably we a `Parent Class` from which both of your classes [`inherit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance).

**Parent Class:**

```cs
// System Base Class
public class System {
    // Member Variables.
    [SerializeField]
    private int id;
    [SerializeField]
    private string name;
    [SerializeField]
    private double cost;
    [SerializeField]
    private Sprite sprite;
    
    // Constructor.
    public Security(int id, string name, double cost, Sprite sprite) {
        // Set Member Variables.
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.sprite = sprite;
    
        Debug.Log("New System created");
    }
}
```

After you've created that `Parent Class` you can [`inherit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance) from it and then set the values in your `Child Class`.

**Electricity Child Class:**

```cs
public class Electricity : System {
    // Member Variables.
    [SerializeField]
    private bool isPlaced;
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 position;
    
    // Constructor.
    public Electricity(int id, string name, float power, double cost, 
        Sprite sprite, bool placed, Vector3 position) {
        // Set Member Variables.
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.power = power;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.sprite = sprite;
        this.isPlaced = placed;
        this.position = position;
    
        Debug.Log("New Electricity created");
    }
}
```

---

Additionally you can use use the function for both `Child Classes`. If you use [`Generic Methods (T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods).

```cs
public void StartBuildingSystem(List<T> list, int count, string name) {
    uiPhone.SetActive(false);
    uiPlacement.SetActive(true);
    PlacingAreas(GetActiveBluePrint(name), GetActiveType(list, name));
    activeBuildingType = GetActiveBuildingType(name);
    //uiPlacement.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I heard and thought about kind of a base class with subclasses and a struct like this but with my experience i wasnt sure if this is the way to do it without asking.

Thank you.